# Python3 Django issues regarding paths and custom decorators

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-class-based-views

Rather new to `Django` first time using it. Python is not my strong point in a web context - I'm having issues with my custom decorator I made that will decode the jwt from all requests not really sure what it's looking for.

The error message can be found at the very bottom. Below are what my files look like I'm simply trying to use the `verify_token()` as a decorator to include my custom token checker when receiving an HTTP request ( please don't recommend simple-jwt or django session token ) ultimately not what we want to do as we're working with legacy tables from other DBS and don't want any abstraction)

**decorators.py**

```
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied
import jwt


def verify_token(function):
    def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request:
            print('========='.format(request))
            jwt.decode(request, 'secret', algorithms=['HS256'])

        else:
            raise PermissionDenied
        wrap.__doc__ = function.__doc__
        wrap.__name__ = function.__name__
        return wrap
```

**views.py**

```
from .User_Predictions.PredictionService import PredicitonController
from django.http import JsonResponse
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from .decorators import verify_token


class UserPredictions(APIView):
    @verify_token
    def generate_full_report(request):
        _predction = PredicitonController()
        results = _predction.compile_complete_predition()
        return JsonResponse(results, safe=False)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import UserPredictions


urlpatterns = [
    path('compilePredictions/', UserPredictions.generate_full_report, name='generate_full_report')
]
```

.

```
├── Analytics
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── settings.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   └── wsgi.cpython-37.pyc
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── authentication
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   └── views.py
├── biometrics
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── bodyfatPrediciton.py
│   ├── Config.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── templates
│   │   ├── bodyfat.html
│   │   ├── github.html
│   │   └── upload_bodyfat.html
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── TorsoDimensions.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── db.sqlite3
├── dump.rdb
├── extraction
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── ExtractionQueryService.py
│   ├── ExtractionServices.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __pycache__
│   │       └── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── admin.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── ExtractionQueryService.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── ExtractionServices.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── models.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   └── views.cpython-37.pyc
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── loginServices
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── Authentication.py
│   ├── decorators.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __pycache__
│   │       └── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── admin.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── Authentication.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── models.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   └── views.cpython-37.pyc
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── manage.py
├── models.py
├── nutrition
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   ├── 0002_auto_20191007_0323.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __pycache__
│   │       ├── 0001_initial.cpython-37.pyc
│   │       ├── 0002_auto_20191007_0323.cpython-37.pyc
│   │       └── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── PredictFood.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── admin.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── models.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── PredictFood.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── serializers.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   └── views.cpython-37.pyc
│   ├── serializers.py
│   ├── TempImages
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── food.html
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── output
**├── predictions**
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
*│   ├── decorators.py*
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __pycache__
│   │       └── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── admin.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── decorators.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── models.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   └── views.cpython-37.pyc
│   ├── tests.py
*│   ├── urls.py*
│   ├── User_Predictions
*│   └── views.py*
├── README.txt
└── TempImages
```

ERROR MESSAGES

```
/Development/Backends_HealthApp/mainBackend/ModelBackend/Analytics/predictions/urls.py", line 6, in <module>
    path('compilePredictions/', UserPredictions.generate_full_report, name='generate_full_report')
  File "/home/travjav/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 73, in _path
    raise TypeError('view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().')
TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().
```

Not really sure what's going on here - I can use other non-custom decorators with no issues

Comment: I think error must be due to your urls.py. class based views use convention as_view() when being referenced while defining a url. please check in django docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/#simple-usage-in-your-urlconf

Comment: As you are using an ApiView which is detailed in DRF docs, please have a look if you are doing it right: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/3-class-based-views/

Comment: the decorator is not correct. first you dont return anything from it  ( at least, how it is written now ) and second , it does not call the decorated function at all

Answer (score 0):

it was the way the decorator was created.

I changed the function name, but you can see the difference.

```
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied
import jwt
from functools import wraps
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse

def protected_endpoint(function):
    @wraps(function)
    def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
        auth = request.headers.get('Authorization').split()[1]
        if auth is None:
            return PermissionDenied
        elif auth is not None:
            try:
                session_token = jwt.decode(auth, '', 'utf-8')
            except jwt.DecodeError:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid Token')
        if session_token:
            return function(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    return wrap
```